# What's the problem with Clifford's algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, clifford-algebras

I've been searching trough the internet for more information about Clifford's algebras, and for what I've been reading, Clifford's vector system appears to be "unifying" vector system, in particular I've find some results that show that in a Clifford algebra the Maxwell's equations can  be reduced to $$\partial F=J$$
It inded seems a great subject of algebras and it is very interesting.
My question is: why can't we just "implement" this algebra in our "daily" system, I mean, why do we learn Gibb's algebra instead of Clifford's one.
What is the Gibbs advantage? What is missing in Clifford algebras? Is it not well defined yet?

Thank you and have a great weekend.

Comment: Nothing's missing, it's just a question of history and personal tastes.

Comment: Clifford algebras are around for a long time but are not too often used in physics. Sticking to Maxwell, if you read the original Maxwell you will find out that he used quaternions which can be interpreted as ... one guess. Quantum mechanics uses them in the form of spinors. There are few books around that emphasize their use for physics and then there are the plain mathematical texts. They are also sometimes called 'geometric algebra'. A classical text would be Artin (about 1957)